# How to fetch first N records from a group of columns based upon date in excel or sql?

Tags: excel, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a Table like:

Sr.no.....Product Code...Product ID...Region...Year_month

1..................XXX...................123............North..........201605
2..................XXX...................123............North..........201604
3..................YYY...................124............South..........201510
4..................YYY...................124............South..........201509
5..................YYY...................124............South..........201507
6..................ZZZ...................125............West...........201612
7..................ZZZ...................125............West...........201611
8..................ZZZ...................125............West...........201604
9..................ZZZ...................125............West...........201603

Group of product code,ProductID,Region is unique, and I need first n number of records per group, with consecutive decreasing months without break, so my output would be like:

Sr.no.....Product Code...Product ID...Region...Year_month
1..................XXX...................123............North..........201605
2..................XXX...................123............North..........201604
3..................YYY...................124............South..........201510
4..................YYY...................124............South..........201509
5..................ZZZ...................125............West...........201612
6..................ZZZ...................125............West...........201611

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data it looks like Sr.no is a generated value and not part of the record data.  The following query will generate partitioned row numbers in the subfactored query t1.  The output query will then add the Sr.no row numbers as the data is returned, and will limit the number of rows returned per group:

```
with t1 as (
 SELECT Product_Code
      , Product_ID
      , Region
      , Year_month
      , row_number() over (partition by product_code, prodcut_id, region order by year_month desc) rn
   FROM your_data
)
 select row_number() over (order by product_code, prodcut_id, region, year_month desc) Sr_no
      , Product_Code
      , Product_ID
      , Region
      , Year_month
   from t1
  where rn <= 2;
```

To return the first N consecutive Year_Month records partitioned on the product_code, product_id and region you can use the [Tabibitosan](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/data-ruminations/tabibitosan-the-traveler-technique-in-sql-74049) [method](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2014/01/tabibitosan.html) whereby records are grouped by calculating a row number and a sequence number, and subtracting one from the other.  The row number is easy, and can be computed with the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function.  The sequence needs to be some function which increments by 1 for each record within the current group.  For your data we can use the `MONTHS_BETWEEN()` function combined with the analytic `MAX(year_month)`.  Subtracting `RN` from `SEQ` yields `GRP`.  Now to get just the first group, all you need to do is limit to `GRP=0`:

```
with your_data(Sr_no, Product_Code, Product_ID, Region, Year_month) as (
  select 1, 'XXX', 123, 'North', date '2016-05-01' from dual union all
  select 2, 'XXX', 123, 'North', date '2016-04-01' from dual union all
  select 3, 'YYY', 124, 'South', date '2015-10-01' from dual union all
  select 4, 'YYY', 124, 'South', date '2015-09-01' from dual union all
  select 5, 'YYY', 124, 'South', date '2015-07-01' from dual union all
  select 6, 'ZZZ', 125, 'West', date '2016-12-01' from dual union all
  select 7, 'ZZZ', 125, 'West', date '2016-11-01' from dual union all
  select 8, 'ZZZ', 125, 'West', date '2016-04-01' from dual union all
  select 9, 'ZZZ', 125, 'West', date '2016-03-01' from dual
), t1 as (
 SELECT Product_Code
      , Product_ID
      , Region
      , Year_month
      , row_number()
        over (partition by product_code, product_id, region
                  order by year_month desc) rn
      , months_between( max(year_month)
                        over (partition by product_code, product_id, region)
                      , year_month) + 1 seq
      , months_between( max(year_month)
                        over (partition by product_code, product_id, region)
                      , year_month) + 1
      - row_number()
        over (partition by product_code, product_id, region
                  order by year_month desc) grp
   FROM your_data
)
select * from t1 where grp = 0;

PRO PRODUCT_ID REGIO YEAR_MONTH                   RN        SEQ        GRP
--- ---------- ----- -------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
XXX        123 North 01-MAY-2016 00:00:00          1          1          0
XXX        123 North 01-APR-2016 00:00:00          2          2          0
YYY        124 South 01-OCT-2015 00:00:00          1          1          0
YYY        124 South 01-SEP-2015 00:00:00          2          2          0
ZZZ        125 West  01-DEC-2016 00:00:00          1          1          0
ZZZ        125 West  01-NOV-2016 00:00:00          2          2          0

 6 rows selected
```

Comment: This is just a sample data,there is no fixed limit.There can be a group with 30 occurrences and all have consecutive decreasing year_month, in that case i would be needing all of those in my result set. i need only those first records per group which have consecutive decreasing year_month.

Comment: Ok your posting wasn't very clear on how the first N was determined, so I took it to mean the first 2 as shown in the sample output.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, set up a helper column in column H containing the formula

```
=IF(OR(B2&C2&D2<>B1&C1&D1,AND(EDATE(E2,1)=E1,H1<>"")),A2,"")
```

and filter on this column, excluding blanks.

This assumes your data is sorted in the way shown in the sample and that the dates are actual dates.

[image]